# SEO history of recycled domain name

Tags: search, dns, seo, search-engines

I have purchased a recycled domain name and I have just been told that if I use the recycled domain name (that I now own) I will inherit any penalties that the recycled domain name may have attracted in its previous life.

Is there any way that I can check if there are penalties associated with the recycled domain name that I now own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual penalties are rare, and most will be algorithmically generated.  This means that any penalties caused by on-site black-hat SEO should go when you upload a new site.

I imagine the only real penalties you have to worry about are from bad backlinks.  Check these, and if there are lots of spam links (directory / articles etc) pointing to your homepage, then there is a high chance that it will have some negative effect on your search position.  Even if it doesn't have a penalty now, bad backlinks could well trigger a future penalty.  Lots of sites were not hit when the Penguin update first came out, but then got a penalty when it was updated.

If you bought the domain from a 'domain flipper', then it almost certainly will have or will get a penalty.  They usually use automated spam software to build the pagerank.

Matt Cutts from Google's advice may help:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGUw9oS5csI

(See what messages webmaster tools gives you)

Answer (score 1):

Use GWT to desalow all infected backlinks form the old domaine name

Comment: Do you mean "disavow"?   Can you post more detailed instructions about how that can be done?